# How to implement round-robin order for PriorityBlockingQueue?

Tags: java, multithreading, priority-queue, java.util.concurrent, round-robin

I have a `PriorityBlockingQueue`. A single thread consumes one message at a time from this queue and processes it. Several further threads are inserting messages into the queue. The producer threads assign an integral priority to each message they submit. A static `AtomicLong` is used to assign every message a unique, monotonically incrementing ID. The `Comparator` of the queue orders messages by this priority first, and then equal priority messages are ordered by ID (lowest ID first.)

**Problem:** Sometimes one producer submits a large number of messages. This then starves the other producers of having their messages processed. What I'd like to do, is have the consumer round-robin between producers for equal priority messages (while still processing equal priority messages of a single producer in submission order). But I cannot work out how to write the `Comparator` to do this.

Another alternative I considered is having a separate queue for each producer. However, I don't think that could work, since I'm not aware of any way for single thread to wait on multiple queues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel like it's more straightforward to implement this with one `Queue` for each producer. One thread can't wait on multiple `Queue`s, but you could combine all of the `Queue`s into one helper class so that it doesn't need to.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

import javax.annotation.concurrent.GuardedBy;

public class RoundRobin<P, E> {
    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final Condition added = lock.newCondition();

    @GuardedBy("lock") private final Map<P, Queue<E>> queues = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    public boolean add(P producer, E item) {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            if (!queues.containsKey(producer)) {
                queues.put(producer, new PriorityBlockingQueue<>());
            }

            added.signalAll();
            return queues.get(producer).add(item);
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public Iterator<E> roundRobinIterator() {
        return new Iterator<E>() {
            private Iterator<? extends Queue<E>> i = null;
            private boolean singlePass = true;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public E next() {
                lock.lock();
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        if (i == null || !i.hasNext()) {
                            i = queues.values().iterator();
                            singlePass = true;
                        }

                        while (i.hasNext()) {
                            Queue<E> q = i.next();
                            if (!q.isEmpty()) {
                                if (singlePass) {
                                    // copy the iterator to prevent
                                    // ConcurrentModificationExceptions
                                    singlePass = false;
                                    i = copy(i);
                                }
                                return q.poll();
                            }
                        }

                        if (singlePass) {
                            // If singlePass is true then we just checked every
                            // queue and they were all empty.
                            // Wait for another element to be added.
                            added.await();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException(e.getMessage());
                } finally {
                    lock.unlock();
                }
            }

            private <T> Iterator<? extends T> copy(Iterator<? extends T> i) {
                List<T> copy = new ArrayList<>();
                while (i.hasNext()) {
                    copy.add(i.next());
                }
                return copy.iterator();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this idea (in particular use of ReenterantLock and Condition). I'm going to try something similar.

Comment: Since you've got a ReentrantLock on the outside, you don't need a PriorityBlockingQueue on the inside, a PriorityQueue will be fine - double locking would give worse performance and greater risk of deadlocks (not with your current code, but possible with future changes).

Comment: Also, your solution has a separate priority queue for each producer, when I need a higher priorities to apply across messages of different producers. You have LinkedHashMap<Producer,PriorityQueue>; I ended up doing essentially Map<Priority,LinkedHashMap<Producer,PriorityQueue>>. I'm accepting your answer since it got me thinking on the right track and is the closest to what I ended up actually doing.

Answer (score 2):

I think I would do something like that:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Queue;

public class RRQueue<M> {
    private final ThreadLocal<Queue<M>> threadQueue = new ThreadLocal<>();
    private final List<Queue<M>> queues;
    private int current = 0;

    public RRQueue() {
        this.queues = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public synchronized void add(M msg) {
        Queue<M> queue = threadQueue.get();
        if (queue == null) {
            queue = new LinkedList<>(); // or whatever
            queues.add(queue);
            threadQueue.set(queue);
        }
        queue.add(msg);
        notify();
    }

    public synchronized M get() throws InterruptedException {
        while (true) {
            for (int i = 0; i < queues.size(); ++i) {
                Queue<M> queue = queues.get(current);
                current = (current+1)%queues.size();
                if (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                    return queue.remove();
                }
            }
            wait();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this would work. However, it doesn't address priorities.

Answer (score 0):

It's all in how you allocate the IDs. Allocate them *N* apart, where *N* is the number of producers, and add each producer's index to that. Then reading them sequentially will yield a round-robin order. You'll have a tiny bit of bookkeeping to do to know when to increment the underlying ID, which will happen when you reach *Nx-1* for any *x*.

Comment: With two producers, are you saying to allocate even IDs to the first producer, odd IDs to the second? Suppose producer #1 submits 10 messages, which are fully processed - it consumes the first ten odd IDs. Some time later, producer #1 submits 10 messages, which get the next ten odd IDs. Simultaneously, producer #2 submits 10 messages, which consume the first ten even IDs. Won't this result in producer #2's first batch being processed before producer #1's second batch? That's not round robin of outstanding messages.

Comment: No. You would have incremented the underlying ID as per my last sentence, so in your example the IDs would run 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,19, ...

Comment: So you would have a counter, which increments by N (where N is current producer count), and an array sized N of boolean flags, initially all false. When producer x requests an ID, if flags[x] is false, set flags[x]=true; if flags[x] is true, increment counter by N, set all flags to false, set flags[x]=true; then, in either case, return counter+x? I assume also a synchronised block to protect the counter and the array. Also, to change producer count dynamically, would need to resize array, setting all its values to false, incrementing counter.

Comment: I haven't thought out the details of the bookkeeping, and that's not necessarily the only way to do it, but the sequence I gave is the one you wanted, yes?

Comment: Suppose producer #1 submits 100 messages. So far 50 of them have been processed. Now producer #2 submits 100 messages. Due to incrementing the underlying ID, won't all of producer #2's messages have higher ID numbers than producer #1's, so none of them will be processed until producer #1's are done? That isn't round-robin.

Answer (score 0):

A round robin among N producers can be achieved using a PriorityBlockingQueue as follows.

Maintain N AtomicInteger counters for each of the producers and a global counter as a tie breaker in case the producer counters are equal.

When adding to the Q incement counter for the producer and also global counter and store into Q object. The comparator for Q will order based on Producer counter 1st and then the global counter value stored in the Q object.

However when objects of one producer is empty for sometime in the Q the corresponding counter falls behind and it will start hogging the Q when objects start coming in.

To avoid this maintain a volatile variable which is updated with the producer counter of the object when de-queued. After incrementing the producer counter during en-queue if the value is less than the last de-queued counter in volatile variable reset the counter to that value + 1.